# Loopback4 Error in dependency injection: is not bound to any value in context application

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4

i have this error

`Unhandled error in POST /client: 500 Error: The key 'controllers.pointController' is not bound to any value in context application`

My class

```
constructor(
        @repository(ClientRepository)
        public clientRepository: ClientRepository,           
        // Controllers            
        @inject('controllers.pointController')
        public pointController: PointController,

    ) {
    }
// functions
```

i follow the documentarion of loopback4 and dependency injection, but doesn't work

any idea?

Answer (score 3):

By default, LoopBack uses PascalCase keys when binding controller classes, see e.g. this test:

[https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/0444120cda7119c66bc2170f4817e67d8dc9d312/packages/core/src/**tests**/unit/application.unit.ts#L25-L33](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/0444120cda7119c66bc2170f4817e67d8dc9d312/packages/core/src/__tests__/unit/application.unit.ts#L25-L33)

```
expect(binding.key).to.equal('controllers.MyController');
```

Your example does not provide enough information, so I'll assume your controller is defined as a class `PointController` in `src/controllers/point.controller.ts` file and you are using `@loopback/boot` to load and register your application's artifacts.

**In that case, you need to fix your code as follows - notice the upper-case `P`:**

```
@inject('controllers.PointController')
```

**Additional information**

In the future, you can use debug logs to find binding keys created for the different artifacts. On Unix (MacOS, Linux):

```
DEBUG=loopback:context:binding npm start
```

In the debug log, you should see a message like this:

```
loopback:context:binding Bind controllers.PointController to class PointController
```

The part `controllers.PointController` is the binding key to use for `@inject`, the part `PointController` is the name of the controller class.